# Why Does MongoDB give a E11000 duplicate key error on ng-click in a form

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

While using the MEAN stack, I ran into some issues trying to update my data via the PUT method.

I have a very simple Angular Form:

```
<form ng-submit="vm.createQuote()">
    <label>Author</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.quote.author">

    <label>Text</label>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="4" ng-model="vm.quote.text"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">CREATE</button>
    <button ng-click="vm.updateQuote()">UPDATE</button>
</form>
```

I have a node application using Express and Mongoose(MongoDB). I have tested the REST Api using POSTMAN. Everything works fine on the backend.

When I try to update a certain Quote using the form update button (triggers an $http.put), I get a MongoDB Error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.quotes.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('55acecfcee620c7a04e9641c') }
```

Although I get this error, my data is updated correctly in the DB. The issue has to come from Angular, because with POSTMAN, all my HTTP requests finish without errors. I have checked that both my requests (via Postman & Angular) have the same headers and body.

Any idea why my requests work in POSTMAN, and not in my Angular app?

Comment: Are you sending an object with an ID? For example, are you populating the form with an existing object, then trying upsert that same object with modified data? If so that would cause an ID collision

Comment: Yes, apparently the form element was sending a POST with the object containing an already existing ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While going through the [ngSubmit documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) I noticed that I was using ngClick AND ngSubmit in my form. This is a bad thing as explained in the [angular form documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action).

Apparently the PUT request is happening correctly when I trigger the update (that's why my data in correctly updated). But because I am using ngSubmit AND ngClick, the form element itself is also doing a POST request, which results in the MongoDB error.

The reason the MongoDB error is thrown, is because the POST request is using the using the response body from the PUT request as it's own body.
That results in a duplicate key error, because the object in the body has an id that already exists in the DB.

The fixed form:

```
<form>
    <label>Author</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.quote.author">

    <label>Text</label>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="4" ng-model="vm.quote.text"></textarea>

    <button ng-click="vm.createQuote()">CREATE</button>
    <button ng-click="vm.updateQuote()">UPDATE</button>
</form>
```